# C++ `using namespace` directive makes global-scope operator disappear?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, operator-overloading

For reasons I do not understand, the following C++ code fails to compile on VS 2022 (dialect set to C++20):

```
#include <compare>

namespace N1
{}

namespace N1::N2
{
    class A {};
    A operator-(A&);
}

std::strong_ordering operator-(std::strong_ordering o);

namespace N1
{
    using namespace N2; // (1) !!!

    std::strong_ordering foo();
    inline std::strong_ordering bar()
    {
        return -foo(); // (2) !!!
    }
}
```

At (2), the compiler files a complaint: `error C2678: binary '-': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::strong_ordering' (or there is no acceptable conversion)`.

When the `using namespace` directive at (1) is removed, the compiler happily finds the `operator-` defined at global scope for the `std::strong_ordering` type.

This gives rise to a set of questions:

1. Is this VS 2022 behavior (a) a bug, (b) allowed or even (c) mandatory according to the language standard?
2. In case of (b) or (c), how? Which specific sentences in the standard allow/mandate the compiler to *not* find the `operator-` at global scope?
3. How would you suggest to work around the issue, presuming that the `using namespace` directive is there to stay?

[Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/s3WKbWxaz)

Comment: Despite popular belief, a compiler isn't supposed to find the biggest candidate set it can. Once there are candidates, outward scope lookup stops.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your compiler is correct, and I would expect other compilers to agree.

For the behaviour of a *using-directive*, see C++20 [namespace.udir]/2:

> A *using-directive* specifies that the names in the nominated namespace can be used in the scope in which the *using-directive* appears after the *using-directive*. During unqualified name lookup (6.5.2), the names appear
> as if they were declared in the nearest enclosing namespace which contains both the *using-directive* and the nominated namespace.

In other words, if `N1` contains `using namespace N2;`, then only for the purposes of unqualified name lookup, names in `N2` will appear as if they are in the lowest common ancestor namespace of `N1` and `N2`. Since `N2` is inside `N1`, the lowest common ancestor namespace is just `N1`, and that means the `operator-` in `N2` appears inside `N1` when unqualified name lookup is performed.

This means that unqualified lookup for `operator-` will find `N2::operator-`, and it won't proceed to the global namespace to continue searching for additional declarations. See [basic.lookup.unqual]/1:

> In all the cases listed in 6.5.2, the scopes are searched for a declaration in the order listed in each of the respective categories; name lookup ends as soon as a declaration is found for the name. If no declaration is found, the program is ill-formed.

To work around the issue, there are two strategies. One is to place the `operator-` for your type in the namespace where that type is declared, so it can be found via argument-dependent lookup. However, you are not allowed to add operator overloads to the `std` namespace. The other strategy is to redeclare the `operator-` you want using a *using-declaration*:

```
using namespace N2;
using ::operator-;
```

This effectively brings the `operator-` that you want "one level deeper", putting it at the same level as the other `operator-` that appears thanks to the *using-directive*, so unqualified name lookup will find both, and the compiler will perform overload resolution.

Comment: I hadn't thought of the `using ::operator-` approach; that should make for reasonably clean code without messing with `std::`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm now working around the issue by having the `operator-` live in `std::`, i.e.:

```
...
namespace std
{
    strong_ordering operator-(strong_ordering o);
}
...
```

However, I'm not really sure whether it is good practice to mess with the `std::` namespace; comments welcome.

Comment: Extending `std` this way causes undefined behavior: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std

Comment: That's pretty much what I was worried about. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: You can't add anything to `std` unless documentation says you can (like specialization for `std::hash`). Anyway his works because of [Argument-dependent lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl).